# Plotting violin plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, violin-plot

I am trying to create a violin plot using a data frame in the long format. The data frame has 2 columns headed group (containing 2 factors- efficient and inefficient) and Glucose m+6 with corresponding numerical values.

I have tried plotting a violin plot using the following code:

```
Dta_lng %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x= Group, y= `Glucose m+6`, fill= Group)) +
  geom_violin(show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_jitter(aes(fill=Group),width=0.1, alpha=0.6, pch=21, color="black")
```

This is the resulting plot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrtbU.jpg

The console also gives 50 warning messages saying groups with fewer than two data points have been dropped.

This is the data I'm working with:

> Dta_lng

## A tibble: 66 x 2

| Group | `Glucose m+6` |
| --- | --- |
|  |  |
| Efficient | 0.47699999999999998 |
| Efficient | 0.376 |
| Efficient | 0.496 |
| Efficient | 0.32500000000000001 |
| Efficient | 8.8999999999999996E-2 |
| Efficient | 4.5999999999999999E-2 |
| Efficient | 0.21299999999999999 |
| Efficient | 8.2000000000000003E-2 |
| Efficient | 0.35899999999999999 |
| Efficient | 0.30599999999999999 |

## ... with 56 more rows

The first 30 rows are efficient the last 35 are inefficient in the group column.

Comment: If you post some data we can surely help you.

Comment: Hi I've added some sample data . Cheers.

Comment: your glucose column is stored as character or factor. convert to numeric with `as.numeric`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps like this:

Data: (Note the different labels!)

```
df <- data.frame(
  group = c(sample(c("efficient", "inefficient"), 1000, replace = TRUE)),
  Glucose_m_6 = rnorm(1000) 
)
```

The violin plot with scatter plot:

```
ggplot(data = df, 
       aes(x = group, y = Glucose_m_6, fill = group)) +
  geom_violin(scale = "count", trim = F, adjust = 0.7, kernel = "cosine") +
  geom_point(aes(y = Glucose_m_6), 
             position = position_jitter(width = .25), size = 0.9, alpha = 0.8)
```

[image]